# Shutdown nodes from within a ROS node

Tags: ros, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a follow up question to [Shutdown system (computer) with a ROS node](http://answers.ros.org/question/214554/shutdown-system-computer-with-a-ros-node/).

Since the system in which the ROS is running is connected to some motors I would like to know if it is possible to close nodes from within a different ROS node.

Since the system is powered by some batteries, the shutdown procedure I would like to achieve is something like this:
Once battery level is below a certain threshold:

- Close/stop all nodes
- Stop rosbag recording
- Shutdown system

However I have no clue how to "Close/stop all nodes" and "Stop rosbag recording" from within a certain node (The same node used to check the battery level).

Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218412/shutdown-nodes-from-within-a-ros-node/) by [nwanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/23134/nwanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-09-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [rosnode.kill_nodes](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rosnode/html/) to shutdown nodes. I'm not sure this is necessary though - the system shutdown command (`shutdown`) should send `SIGTERM` to all processes so they can end gracefully.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nwanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/23134/nwanda/) on 2015-09-29**:
Would that stop the rosbag recording properly so that I can use the bag-file after rebooting? And is there a way to select which nodes to "kill" or the only way is to shutdown every node with rosnode.kill_nodes?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-09-29**:
That's a good question: I tried `kill -15` with rosbag which seems like it may not properly close the file. Your best bet would just be to just try rebooting with an active `rosbag record` to see what happens. `rosnode kill`ing rosbag does seem to work fine though.